# permutation and combination infinte supply

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Amika wants to buy 4 cupcakes from an infinite supply of three types of cupcakes: chocolate, vanilla & gems-laden. In how many
different ways can she buy cupcakes, if :

(1) order of buying the cupcakes is important, and

(2) arbitrary order is permitted

Comment: Do you care what order she buys them in?  What have you tried? Where are you stuck?  For a problem this small you could try to list the possibilities by hand.

Comment: Can it then be 3^4=81 ways??

Comment: @Rohan:  that would be correct if the order matters.  I suspect it is not supposed to matter, that getting choc-choc-van-van is the same as getting van-choc-choc-van, but if we don't know it is hard to answer the question.

Comment: Gem-laden?  What, is she buying cupcakes for a certain purple dragon in Equestria?  I'm wondering if this is just an unusual translation error and it was intended to be "sprinkles" instead or something.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose order is important.  first cupcake $3$ ways, second $3$ ways, third in $3$ ways, fourth in $3$ ways, So, $3^4$ in total

if order is not important, it is $\dbinom{3+4-1}{4}$
*(this is similar to the stars and bars pattern I guess)*

Answer (score -1):

The number of different ways she can buy 4 cupcakes is $3^4=81$ ways because she can choose arbitrarily any cupcake from $3$ varieties. But, if order of choosing is unimportant, then it is $\binom{3+4-1}{3}$ which equals $15$. The formula in the general case is taken from [combination with repititions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208377/combination-with-repetitions)