# Visualizing combinations with repetitions allowed.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

So I fully understand:

Permutations without repetitions: $\dfrac {n!}{(n-r)!}$

Permutations with repetitions: $n^r$

Combinations without repetitions: $\dfrac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}$

But I'm having problems finding resources online that visually explain combinations with repetitions: $$\dfrac{(n+r-1)!}{(n-1)!r!}$$

I would be very grateful if anyone could give me a good visual, step by step explanation of how they work. Maybe use the case of choosing $3$ letters from a set of A, B and C, with repetitions allowed.

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208377/combination-with-repetitions

Comment: Hmmm. But I how can it applied to a case such as the one I mentioned with the letters A, B and C?

Comment: For that, you might want to check out the examples here: http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~mlerma/courses/cs310-05s/notes/dm-gcomb :)

Comment: Also there are a few very similar examples here on Math Exchange, just check out the "Related" tabs :)

Comment: Wait but why does the 18 upvotes answer have $k-1$ at the bottom of the binomial instead of $k$?