# Finding number of unordered $k$-tuples from a given $n$-tuple.

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we are given $n$ different objects.
I wanted to find the number of unordered $k$-tuples with entries from this set of objects and with repetition allowed for arbitrary $k$.
It turns out that it is not that easy and I'm finding it hard to find a closed form formula or at least something in terms of an elementary function.
Can someone help me on this one?

Comment: Welcome to math stackexchange! You'll get a better response if you format your question using MathJax. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You'll find an answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208377/combination-with-repetitions

Comment: You might be interested in "multisets": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset